# problema con uso de la función gets en [C]

Tags: c

Al compilar una estructura while y entra en un caso el cual me pide que introducir el nombre de una persona y luego lo imprima con la utilización de gets para poder usar espacio compila bien. Pero al ejecutar la consola solo muestra el mensaje "ingrese el nombre del contacto" y finaliza.

Lo que está en comentarios es el proceso para comparar si el nombre introducido se encuentra en la agenda ya realizada anteriormente para ver si el nombre esta en ella o no.

Ya intenté cambiando la posición del char nombre y lo hice en función pero el resultado es el mismo siempre.

```
switch (op){
case 1: buscarNum(vectorContactos,vectorTelefonos);break;
case 2: buscarNombre(vectorContactos,vectorTelefonos);break;
case 2:
char nombre[100];
puts("introduzca un nombre");
gets(nombre);
puts(nombre);break;
int existe,j;
existe = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<100; i++){
        if (strcmp(nombre,vectorContactos[i])!=0){
        existe = 1;
        j = i;
        }
    }
printf ("%d. %s %ld",j,vectorContactos[j],vectorTelefonos[j]);
    if (existe != 0){
        printf ("No hay ningún contacto con ese nombre");
    }
    else{
        printf("%s se encuentra en su agenda",nombre);  
    }
    ;break;
```

Comment: Lo siento pero he leído tu pregunta tres veces y no entiendo nada de lo que dices en la descripción (las comas y los puntos se inventaron para algo). Y el código tampoco tiene sentido. Tienes dos `case` con el mismo valor, hay `breaks` y luego instrucciones, el `switch` no se cierra. Hablas de comentarios que no están en el código y de un `while` que tampoco. No sé qué quieres que te contestemos, la verdad...

Answer (score 0):

Como dice PaperBirdMaster "Tienes dos case con el mismo valor, hay `breaks` y luego instrucciones, el `switch` no se cierra. Hablas de comentarios que no están en el código y de un `while` que tampoco." En definitiva tu código presenta graves errores de sintáxis.

No se de que `while` estás hablando, en el código que subes no hay ningún `while`

Además, tampoco incluiste el código de la función o procedimiento `buscarNum(vectorContactos,vectorTelefonos);` ni `buscarNombre(vectorContactos,vectorTelefonos);`

Acá un acercamiento al código correcto:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    int op;
    char nombre[100];
    printf("Ingrese una opcion");
    scanf("%d",&op);
    switch (op){
    case 1: 
        buscarNum(vectorContactos,vectorTelefonos);
        break;
    case 2: 
        buscarNombre(vectorContactos,vectorTelefonos);
        break;
    case 3:
        puts("introduzca un nombre");
        gets(nombre);
        puts(nombre);
        break;
        int existe,j;
        existe = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<100; i++){
            if (strcmp(nombre,vectorContactos[i])!=0){
                existe = 1;
                j = i;
            }
        }
        printf ("%d. %s %ld",j,vectorContactos[j],vectorTelefonos[j]);
        if (existe != 0){
            printf ("No hay ningun contacto con ese nombre");
        }
        else{
            printf("%s se encuentra en su agenda",nombre);  
        }
        break;
    default:
        printf("Opcion incorrecta");
    }       
    return 0;
}
```

Tira error porque no tengo ni están definidas las funciones ni `buscarNum(vectorContactos,vectorTelefonos);` ni `buscarNombre(vectorContactos,vectorTelefonos);`